# comprobaciones lógicas con switch en php

Tags: php

Tengo en mi sitio varios formularios diferentes, y para recibir los datos normalmente usaba:

```
if(isset($_POST["formulario1"]) and $_POST["fomulario1"] != ""){}
```

Pero he leído que no se recomienda usar demasiados if-else, por lo que ¿hay alguna manera de hacer todas esas comprobaciones con un switch?, lo intente así:

```
switch($variable){case isset($_POST["formulario1"]) and $_POST["fomulario1"] != "": //codigo}
```

Y así con todas las comprobaciones que debo hacer de los distintos formularios, pero me da un error diciendo que $variable no esta definido. ¿Cómo sería la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Verificas lo mismo dos veces. A veces el código se puede abreviar evitando algunos condicionales, pero para poder hacerlo hace falta ver el contexto real. El código que muestras no permite entender el problema que se quiere resolver/optimizar.

Comment: quiero hacer la comprobación del IF pero en un SWITCH, no se como. No traigo el código real porque es muy extenso y según lo que decían aquí cuando me registre es que evite poner código extenso en las preguntas.

Comment: El `switch` te puede ayudar en algunas situaciones (tampoco en todas), a veces no conviene usarlo, todo depende, por eso te decía que hay que entender el contexto. Para poder ayudarte es fundamental que expliques lo que quieres hacer. Aquí no tiene sentido usarlo, porque veo que sólo evalúas `formulario1`, no veo más `case` quee ese. Para un `case` no tendría sentido usar `switch`

Comment: No tienes que poner todo el código, sino un extracto del mismo que al menos permita entender el contexto, explicando lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: es que son 9 else-if los que uso para evaluar respectivamente los input de 9 formularios diferentes, pense que había manera de no usar tanto if-else por lo que tanto leía sobre el exceso de los mismos

Comment: Nueve `else` tampoco es mucho, pon los 9 para ver si se entiende lo que quieres. A veces se pueden usar otros tipos de estructuras para resolver problemas complejos, como arrays, clases, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**switch** se utiliza cuando lo que quieres hacer es comprobar los valores de una sola **variable**

Es decir:

```
$variable = "aaa";
switch($variable){
   case "aab":
      echo "valor aab";
   break;

   case "aaa":
      echo "valor aaa";
   break;

   default:
      echo "no es ni aab ni aaa";
   break;
}
```

**Switch no funciona con condiciones multiples**

Pero si no quieres usar **if/else** todo el rato porque te acumula espacios, puedes usar **elseif**

EJEMPLO:

```
if(isset($variable)){
   echo "aaa";
}
elseif(isset($variableDos)){
   echo "bbb";
}
```

Con esto podras usar **if/else** sin tener que acumular mucho espacio

Comment: comprendido, yo creia que el switch era como una alternativa al if-else y buscaba usarlo por lo que dicen del exceso de If, pero ya todo queda claro.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que planteas es evaluar distintos formularios. En ese caso los if me parecen difíciles de evitar, si es un formulario haces tal cosa, si es otro formulario haces otra, etc. Switch hace algo diferente, una variable ($variable en tu caso) puede tomar diferentes valores y en función de ese valor haces determinadas tareas, es otra cosa.

En todo caso lo podrías implementar si en $variable le dijeras al Switch que formulario viene.

En la documentación oficial hay esto:

```
<?php
if ($i == 0) {
    echo "i es igual a 0";
} elseif ($i == 1) {
    echo "i es igual a 1";
} elseif ($i == 2) {
    echo "i es igual a 2";
}

switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i es igual a 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "i es igual a 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "i es igual a 2";
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: todo claro,ambas respuestas me dieron información muy util

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de resolver problemas complejos, si quieres evitar los `if`, es mediante un array.

El array tendría pares clave->valor donde `clave` puede ser un dato numérico o alfanumérico y `valor` sería el dato a usar.

Supongamos que en `$_POST["formulario1"]` recibirás números del `1 al N` y según el número hay que mostrar un mensaje:

```
#Array que reemplazaría los if o el swithc
$mValues=array( 1=>"Valor 1", 2=>"Valor 2", 3=>"Valor 3", 4=>"Etc"); 

#Ejemplos
#Esto sería cualquier valor del $_POST
$post=1;
echo $mValues[$post].PHP_EOL;

$post=4;
echo $mValues[$post];
```

**Salida:**

```
Valor 1
Etc
```

Esto puede hacerse con cualquier tipo de valor. Imaginemos que lo que viene el POST son palabras:

```
$mValues=array( "Marta"=>"Valor para Marta", "Pedro"=>"Valor para Pedro", "Cualquiera"=>"Valor para Cualquiera..."); 

$post="Cualquiera";
echo $mValues[$post].PHP_EOL;

$post="Marta";
echo $mValues[$post];
```

**Salida:**

```
Valor para Cualquiera...
Valor para Marta
```

Como ves, los arrays permiten también escribir un código portable, y abreviar. Imagina que son 50 casos, el array te evita escribir 50 if o 50 case en un switch. Y si hubiera una nueva situación, solamente la agregas al array sin tener que modificar nada más en el código.