# Funcion en Switch

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo A.php en donde hago una consulta mysql y almaceno un dato en un variable, a esa varible le quiero aplicar un Switch pero va a ser tan grande que lo quisiera poner en otro archivo a quien le llamo B.php y lo almacenare en una funcion entonces yo al hacer esto:

```
function ap_num_cd(){       
    switch ($cad) {
        case 40:
            echo "a";
            break;
        case 46:
            echo "b";
            break;
        case 48:
            echo "c";
            break;
    }
}
```

Donde ap_num_cd es el nombre de la funcion y $cad es la variable en donde almaceno el dato que jalo de la base de datos.
Y al llamar la funcion me devuelve un error "Undefined variable"

Comment: En la función no tienes acceso a `$cad`, envíala como parámetro y se resuelve el problema.

Comment: Y como lo podria enviar?
Disculpame recien estoy aprendiendo. Gracias

Comment: Triby, agradesco haberme respondido ya lo solucione poniendo dentro del parentisis la variable al declarar la funcion como al llamarla.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si son muchos `case` otra forma de simplificar sería usando un array donde asociarías en pares clave->valor cada relación ([ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/369839/29967)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás omitiendo el argumendo de la función:

```
function ap_num_cd($cad) {       
    switch ($cad) {
        case 40:
            echo "a";
            break;
        case 46:
            echo "b";
            break;
        case 48:
            echo "c";
            break;
    }
}
```

Y la invocarías, por ejemplo, así:

```
ap_num_cd(40);
```

Comment: Eduardo, agradesco haberme respondido ya lo solucione poniendo dentro del parentisis la variable al declarar la funcion como al llamarla. Gracias de antemano.